# Some of columns not binds in WPF DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpfdatagrid

I am trying to bind data from sql server to WPF Datagrid but unfortunately some of columns binds correctly while some are not. I have this piece of code for data binding..

```
    SqlConnection cn;
    SqlDataAdapter da;
    DataSet ds;

    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        cn = new SqlConnection ("Connection String");
        cn.Open();
    }


    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        da = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from table_1",cn);
        ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
        dataGrid1.ItemsSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
    }
```

Help Pllllllllllllzzzzzzzz

Here is the XML

```
<Window
x:Class="Smart.Window1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Title="Smart"
Loaded="Window_Loaded"
Height="779"
Width="1180">
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions></Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <DataGrid
        AutoGenerateColumns="True"
        Name="dataGrid1"
        IsReadOnly="True"
        Height="870"
        Width="1063"
        Margin="104.5,85,0,0"
        VerticalAlignment="Top"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        Grid.Row="0"
        Grid.Column="0"
        FontSize="15" />
```

....

And Here is the image preview of my form's datagrid

[DataGrid](http://s13.postimage.org/g2926xgx3/image.jpg)

Now you see all columns displays results correctly except column 3,6 and 7.

Comment: Can you please post your xaml and what columns you have and what the result is?

Comment: you need to give us more information.  have you done any debugging?  We don't know your database, have you put a breakpoint on the datasource and made sure that it's 'defaultview' actually has data in it?  I see no try/catches in your code, are there errors at all?

Comment: It's getting better, now only describe what you have and what you expect. Most of us don't have crystal balls to see what your problem is ;)

Comment: [link](http://s13.postimage.org/g2926xgx3/image.jpg)

Comment: Yes Phil I have done debugguing and yes my defaultview has data in it. But i dont know whats happening. You can see my edited post

Answer (score 0):

I Dont know the solution but after facing such a problem, i noticed that column header names having symbols like '.', '/' and all are disappeared. Getting rid of such symbols will solve the problem.